# Google places on Android has strange behavior on some devices

Tags: android, google-places-api

I've created an app that shows some pins on map using `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. App works great on majority of devices but I've got some strange behavior from OnePlus 6 (Andorid 9) and Google Pixel 2 (Andorid Q). I've tested it on couple OnePlus 6 (same Andorid 9) and works just fine so problem is only on certain devices.

**PROBLEM**: The `Activity` with map is restarted in an infinite loop without any crashes.

My code related to map logic is:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    //...

    onInitMap(savedInstanceState);
}

private void onInitMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // needed to get the map to display immediately
    mapView.onResume();

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(MainActivity.this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}

  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    //listen camera moved and stop - when stop then get http data for coordonates and range
    mGoogleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(MapActivity.this);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(MapActivity.this);

    //setup cluster logic
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<SalonMarkerMetaDataObj>(this, mGoogleMap);
    mSalonMarkerRenderer = new SalonMarkerRenderer(MapActivity.this, mGoogleMap, mClusterManager);
    mClusterManager.setRenderer(mSalonMarkerRenderer);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Did you get anything in logs or any where?

Comment: nope, users reported this behavior. I don't have access to that devices but no crashes reported by Crashlytics